# Is there a premium theme for jquery-jtable?

Tags: jquery-jtable

Is there a premium theme for [jquery-jTable](http://www.jtable.org/Themes) like this screenshot :

[image: premium jquery jtable theme]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please checkout [my product](http://codecanyon.net/item/jtable-flat-theme/10279325), it is a premium jTable flat theme.

Features :

1. Using iconfonts instead CSS images
2. Fully support RTL direction
3. 6 Beautiful colors availabe
4. Fully support IE >= 8
5. Only CSS

[**Download**](http://codecanyon.net/item/jtable-flat-theme/10279325)

.

[image]

Comment: Very thank's @dibacode. :)

Answer (score 0):

No. It is custom theme and you should write the same manually